# How to use pinia store with v-for directive whilst keeping it reactive?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, pinia

I have a pinia data store similar to the following code snippet that stores user information and a list of individual orders he is placing:

**order.js**

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export const useOrderStore = defineStore('order', {
  state: () => ({
    username: '',
    orders: reactive([
      { 
        id: '',
        item: '',
        price: ''
      }
    ])
  }),
})
```

Also I am using the v-for directive to render the components that should display the individual orders

**OrdersComp.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="orders_container">
    <div v-for="(order, index) in orders" :key="order.id">
      <OrderComp />
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { useOrderStore } from "@/store/order";
 setup() {
    const { orders } = storeToRefs(useOrderStore())
    return { orders };
  },
</script>
```

How can I access the store data for the *individual* orders in the child component OrderComp

Basically I want something like this:
**OrderComp.vue**

```
<div>
  <p>{{ orders.id }}</p>
  <input v-model="orders.item" />
  <input v-model="orders.price" />
</div>

<script>
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { useOrderStore } from "@/store/order";
 setup() {
    const { orders } = storeToRefs(useOrderStore())
    return { orders };
  },
</script>
```

and still keep its reactive state? How does the child component know which order of the orders array to modify? Can/Should I combine the pinia data store with props that pass the data from parent to child? (Though this seems somewhat wrong for me, as pinia is probably able to replace all data passing between components) And furthermore as item and price are bound to input fields, they should of course dynamically change based on a user input.

Comment: First of all, you need to have a way to update the state without mutation it outside the store, currently there's none

Comment: Do you mean defining actions in the store.js file that allow for modification? Or updating data in methods inside the components? Initially I thought when I access data from the store via storeToRefs and bind it via v-model to e.g. an input field, any update to the input field triggers a store update and is propagated to every component. That is not true in this case?

Comment: Yes, the first option. The state isn't supposed to be modified outside the store. OrderComp shouldn't receive the whole `orders`, just a single order, and it should emit an event to a parent that an order with specified id should be updated instead of updating it by itself, that's how it's usually done. Often forms are not limited to instantly modifying source data, in this case OrderComp will need to have local state that is synced with global one

Comment: Okay so I will bind input data via v-model, emit them on change to the parent component and from there use pinias defined actions to edit the specific values in the datastore. Is this the recommended way of doing so or am I doing something unintended here (anti-pattern)?

Comment: Yes, that's generally the recommended way for such case

Comment: Would you be able to answer your own question with a basic example?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Estus Flasks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask) comments I got it working by emitting events from the child OrderComp to the parent OrdersComp and on each change it invoked a function that modified my orders array at the correct index in the datastore.

So following the example above I did something like this:

**order.js**

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export const useOrderStore = defineStore('order', {
  state: () => ({
    username: '',
    orders: reactive([
      { 
        id: '',
        item: '',
        price: ''
      }
    ])
  }),

  actions: {
    modifyOrder (id, order) {
      var foundIndex = this.orders.findIndex(elem => elem.id == order.id)
      this.orders[foundIndex] = order
      }
   }
})
```

**OrdersComp.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="orders_container">
    <div v-for="(order, index) in order_store.orders" :key="order.id">
      <OrderComp @change="order_store.modifyOrder(index, order)"
        v-model:itemProp="order.item"
        v-model:priceProp="order.price"
      />
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { useOrderStore } from "@/store/order";
export default {
 setup() {
    const order_store = useOrderStore()
    return { order_store };
  },
}
</script>
```

*Note: I use a wrapper function here to emit the inputs, however you can of course emit it directly e.g. via @input/@change*

**OrderComp.vue**

```
<div>
  <input v-model="item" />
  <input v-model="price" />
</div>

<script>
import { useModelWrapper } from "@/modelWrapper";
export default {
  name: "OrderComp",´
  props: {
    itemProp: { type: String, default: "" },
    priceProp: { type: String, default: "" },
  },
emits: [
    "update:itemProp",
    "update:priceProp",
  ],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    return {
      item: useModelWrapper(props, emit, "itemProp"),
      price: useModelWrapper(props, emit, "priceProp"),
    };
  },
}
```

**modelWrapper.js**

```
import { computed } from "vue";
export function useModelWrapper(props, emit, name = "modelValue") {
  return computed({
    get: () => props[name],
    set: (value) => emit(`update:${name}`, value),
  });
}
```